# Как задеплоить телеграмм бота написанный на с# с необходимыми файлами

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Я вообще полный ноль по серверам, и не могу вообще понять с чего начать. Я сделал телеграмм бота который обрабатывает информацию с Excel файлов, и просто отправляет результат в виде сообщения пользователю. Теперь мне надо задеплоить его, но я не знаю как... Может кто-то подсказать или дать ссылку на доку полезную?

Comment: Я надеюсь вы ведь понимаете, что "деплоить" можно в различные места, на различные OS, где нужны различные действия. И вот что-то я в вопросе не увидел ключевого - куда, да и какой тип проекта, и какой .NET версии используется тоже надо знать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ У меня используется 7 дотнет, а файлы Excek хранятся прямо внутри папки с проектом. Тип проекта обычный Console Application

Comment: Куда задеплоить хотите то?

Comment: deploy-f наверное

Comment: Изучил ресурс, так и не нашел что конкретно он требует. Ну, делайте тогда просто ПКМ по проекту - собрать, готово, сверху только не забудьте "Релиз" выбрать а не "Дебаг". Если что сложнее - ПКМ по проекту - Публикация - настраиваете (папка), выбираете нужную архитектуру и прочее, жмете опубликовать, готово. И да, 3 дня вытягивать из вас информацию, скажите, мне оно надо? Думаю вам лично такое не понравилось-бы...

Comment: Извините за задержку просто реально не знаю как закидывать на сервер что либо, и пока сервисами такими не пользовался, но попробую сделать так как вы сказали. Надеюсь у меня получится.